# Car made of boxes teleports on hard collision: Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

I am trying to develop a simple car racing game. The cars comprise of 2 solid cuboids (one engine and one for body) and 4 cylinders. All the objects are connected to each other by fixed joints. The engine is the part that moves and carries the rest with it.

Sometimes on hard/repetitive collision with another car or a wall the car parts behaves crazy for a while and the assemble at another point in the scene.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Fixed joints are helpful to join two gameobjects without parenting one. But as it depends on physics, different forces may have some weird behavior on the gameobjects (though it shouldn't). So, I would suggest that you use a parent object (maybe your car engine) and others as childs. Then you can use only one rigidbody on the parent. You can of course shake the different parts with coding while colliding for visual effects. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is because every object acts as if the collision only affected him. (The engine, the body..) so when you collide too hard, the engine could bounce off in the opposite direction of the body and so do the cylinders. You could try hierarchising them all under one gameobject and adding your collider to that gameobject instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your rigid bodies are considerably heavy then it may cause joints to apply such large forces that the whole model become unstable. Of course, you may try to reduce mass of rigid bodies, but actually there is much more simplier way to define dynamics of a car. Just look for **wheel collider** in Unity and try to replace your cylinders with wheels. And note that you don't have to create separate objects for wheels - all wheel colliders may be attached to single object.